# Filter an Array with 2 conditions at the same time?

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `User` model, which downloads all user from database, store them in a `users` array and display them in a `UITableView`. Above the `UITableView`, I have a `UISearchBar` to allow the users to filter through them.

The search works, but the users have a `usernames_lowercase` and a `displayName` and I'd like to be able to filter `users` array, for both `usernames_lowercase` and `displayName`, store that in `searchUsers` array and then reload/display the results. I cannot figure out how to do that though... and if its even possible to do it with a single array like that.

```
StartNewMessage: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var users = [UserModel]()
    var searchUsers = [UserModel]()
    var searching = false

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return searchUsers.count
        }
        else {
            return users.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UsersChatTVCell") as! UsersChatTVCell
        if searching {
            let searchUser = searchUsers[indexPath.row]
            cell.user = searchUser
        }
        else {
            let user = users[indexPath.row]
            cell.user = user
        }
         return cell
    }
}

extension StartNewMessage: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        let trimmedSearchWord = searchText.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters)
        searchUsers = users.filter({ $0.username_lowercase!.prefix(searchText.count) == trimmedSearchWord.lowercased()})
        searchUsers = users.filter({ $0.displayName!.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText}) // doesn't work, basically rewrites the data
        print(searchText.lowercased())
        searching = true
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `||` (**OR**) operator to specify multiple conditions.

```
searchUsers = users.filter {
    $0.username_lowercase!.prefix(searchText.count) == trimmedSearchWord.lowercased()
    || $0.displayName!.prefix(searchText.count) == searchText
}
```

Comment: Well, I did try that but somehow I've messed up the syntax probably because It wasn't working for me. But yes, it works excellent! Thank you (again! :) )

Answer (score 0):

Create another copy of your user model and use searchText as below:

// self.Copied_User_Model -> Copied User Model

// User_Model -> Original user model

```
self.Copied_User_Model = []
            for item in self.Copied_User_Model {
                if item.user_name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) != false  item.display_Name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) != false{
                    self.Copied_User_Model.append(item)
                } else {

                }
            }

            self.tableview.reloadData()
            if searchText == "" {
                self.Copied_User_Model = self.User_MOdel
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
```

Hope this help.
Thanks.